# Passing variables between classes in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to use the exec resource type to execute a batch file. But I want to pass the value of variable $dsn_64bit from init.pp to install.pp. Please let me know how to achieve that:

Here is my init.pp

```
class exec_batchfile ($dsn_64bit = "false")
{
if $::osfamily == 'windows' {
include exec_batchfile::install
   }
  }
```

Here is my install.pp

```
class exec_batchfile::install 
 {
 if $dsn_64bit == true
{
  $hklm_path = 'HKLM\Software\Oracle'
  $Script_name = 'E:\\Path\\pupp_test64.bat'
}
else
{
   $hklm_path = 'HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Oracle'
  $Script_name = 'E:\\Path\\pupp_test.bat'
 }
    exec { 'exec_batchfile':
       command => "${Script_name}",
       path => $::path,
       logoutput => true,
       unless => "cmd.exe /c reg query ${hklm_path} /v inst_loc",
  }
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since puppet 2.7 dynamic lookup is deprecated, so your code will not work properly. Right now the recommended solution is to use **fully qualified names**. Please follow the [link](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_scope.html#accessing-out-of-scope-variables) to find a comprehensive explanation.

> Whenever you need to refer to a variable in another class, give the variable an explicit namespace: instead of simply referring to $packagelist, use $git::core::packagelist.

Comment: $local_var = "from parent::child" did the trick. +1 for the link. Thanks a lot

Comment: Changed my answer to be more compliant with your comment.